# Compared to wso2 siddhi and spark which uses less resource

Tags: apache-spark, siddhi

I wanted to use a complex event processing engine inside an IoT gateway which will use very minimal resource. So, comparing both wso2 siddhi and spark which uses more resource. As in IoT usecases the device will be of smaller footprint So, which will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Spark recommends 8-16 cores and  8 GB as their [minimum requirement](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/hardware-provisioning.html) whereas [Siddhi supports](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/#system-requirements) runs on a 128 MB, 2 core machine with its minimum requirement. These requirements might have to be tuned anyway according to your usecase.

Furthermore, [Siddhi](https://siddhi.io/) supports enhancing its functionality through its [wide extension list](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/extensions/) so that you can build a fully-fledged event-driven application with Siddhi alone.